# Access the URL of an jQuery Ajax Request in the Callback Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there a way that I can see the URL that was requested when I do an Ajax request with jQuery?

e.g.,

```
var some_data_object = { ...all sorts of junk... }
$.get('/someurl.php',some_data_object, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   var real_url = ? # <-- How do I get this
})
```

How can I access the URL that jQuery actually used to make the request? Perhaps some method/property of `jqHXR`? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: If all else fails you can return it from the server-side code, but I`m guessing there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Is there a way to find this out before the actual request is made ?

Comment: @sanz probably worth noting that modern browsers can break on XHR. i.e., https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-on-xhr

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Set a break point in success method, then watch

```
this.url
```

is the real url for the request.

Comment: Looks like the solution @Chris was looking for but not a good a solution for the case where you need to report or display the URL to the user.

Comment: Instead of a breakpoint, just `console.log(this.url);` inside the `success` callback.

Comment: Also works for error section. When you need to identify which url caused the problem

Answer (score 17):

Here is a possible solution:

1. Catch the ajax call **before** it is sent to the server by implementing the beforeSend callback function.
2. Save the url and the data
3. Report it in the error message you generate.

   ```
   var url = "";

   $.ajax({
     url: "/Product/AddInventoryCount",
     data: { productId: productId, trxDate: trxDate, description: description, reference: reference, qtyInCount: qtyInCount }, //encodeURIComponent(productName)
     type: 'POST',
     cache: false,
     beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
       url = settings.url + "?" + settings.data;
     },
     success: function (r) {
       //Whatever            
     },
     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       handleError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, url);
     }
   });

   function handleError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, url) {
      //Whatever
   }
   ```

Comment: This is the best method, in my opinion, with a slight change.  Rather than all the machinations with error reporting, you can simply console.log or alert the URL from within the beforeSend function.  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 10):

Using `$.ajaxPrefilter`:

```
// Make sure we can access the original request URL from any jqXHR objects
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
  jqXHR.originalRequestOptions = originalOptions;
});

$.get(
  'http://www.asdf.asdf'
).fail(function(jqXHR){
  console.log(jqXHR.originalRequestOptions);
  // -> Object {url: "http://www.asdf.asdf", type: "get", dataType: undefined, data: undefined, success: undefined}
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/

Comment: Using the `$.ajaxPrefilter` is a very good advice! +1 for this one! :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the ajaxSend global handler (http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) provides the url in its settings parameter. You could store a mapping from the xhr object to the url in your ajaxSend callback, then in your success callback look it up given the xhr object that it provides you with.

```
var mappings = {};

$.ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
   mappings[xhr] = settings.url;
});

$.ajax({
  url: "http://test.com",
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    console.log("url = ", mappings[xhr]);
    delete mappings[xhr];
  }
});
```

This has the advantage of not having to modify each $.ajax() object.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, as an addition to airbai's comment -I cannot comment inside his answer,- you can add your own data to the call and retrieve it inside the callbacks. This way you don't have to parse the URL.

In this example JSONP request I have added the variable `user_id` (tested with jQuery 3.2):

```
var request = $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://example.com/user/" + id + "/tasks?callback=?",
    user_id: id,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Success!');
        console.log("User ID: " + this.user_id);
    },
    timeout: 2000
}).fail(function() {
    console.log('Fail!');
    console.log("User ID: " + this.user_id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find it in the docs either. Maybe just add it to the jqXHR object through a "proxy" wrapper like...

I haven't tested this, so you may need to call
`$.param()` and concat to the url. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

```
var myGet = function(url, data, success) {
    $.get(url, data, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       jqXHR.origUrl = url; // may need to concat $.param(data) here
       success(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    });
}
```

usage:

```
var some_data_object = { ...all sorts of junk... }
myGet('/someurl.php',some_data_object, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   var real_url = jqXHR.origUrl;
})
```