# I want to display the complete request sent with $.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

How can I display the complete request sent to the server from a $.get request, 
my request is as follows:

```
$.get("http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search", 
    { 
        'ywsid': xxxx', 
        'term': term, 
        'limit': 20, 
        'location': location, 
        'category': category
    }, function add(data, textStats, jqXHR) {----}}}, 'jsonp');
```

Here I want to display the exact request sent to the server on the webpage.

Comment: depending on your web browser there are different options. You can also use something like OWASP ZAP that abstracts away from specific browsers by setting up a local proxy on your machine to filter the requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem ,

I tried to look into the ajax function in the jquery javascript file. There is a variable "s" in this function. s.url will give the call request made with the data n parameters,

```
function success() {
        // If a local callback was specified, fire it and pass it the data
        if ( s.success ) {
            s.success.call( callbackContext, data, status, xhr );
        }

        // Fire the global callback
        if ( s.global ) {
            trigger( "ajaxSuccess", [xhr, s] );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Firebug.(a debugger for mozilla) You will be able to see the request sent using this tool.

you can print it using something like this..

```
 For Each item In Request.Form
 Response.Write  Request.Form(item) & "<BR />" 
 Next 

$.get("yoururlcontainingtheabove",
 function(data)
{$("#div").html(data)}
,text);
```

Comment: I can see the request I want to display the request, is that possible?

Comment: This seems to ignore the actual question of how to get it on the client side, presumably without extra tools. Yes Charles Proxy or Chrome Developer Tools or whatever would work, but it's not the question.

Comment: Okay.. then do this.. Server side create the request as above, and pass it back to the javascript and print it there.

Answer (score 2):

The jqXHR object might have the full URL (with callback) if that's what you're looking for, though I haven't found it yet (you may have luck looking through here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). If you don't need that just the serialized parameters, try something like this using http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/.

```
var data = {
    'ywsid': 'xxxx',
    'term': term,
    'limit': 20,
    'location': location,
    'category': category
}

var url = "http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search"

doSomethingWith(url, data)

$.get(url, data, function add(data) {
  alert(this.url) // it might be this!
}, 'jsonp');

function doSomethingFancyWith(url, data) {
  var queryString = $.param(data)
  alert(url + "?" + data)
}
```

**Edit:** try `this.url` in the success function. it seemed to work for me in a non json-p situation and is also referenced here [Access the URL of an jQuery Ajax Request in the Callback Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468312/access-the-url-of-an-jquery-ajax-request-in-the-callback-function)

Comment: Yes I tweaked with the jquery.js and its the url in the success function of $.ajax function that gives the request URL.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the actual request that was sent to the server, headers and all, you'll need to use a server-side language to capture the request before it's processed.

This is only possible if you control the server to which you're making the request. Otherwise, to the best of my knowledge, this is impossible.

Comment: Isn't the request information stored in a `jqXHR object` returned by `$.get`?

Comment: The `jqXHR` object is certainly returned, but I know of no way to extract the full request. As I mentioned, to the best of my knowledge, it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

you can use debugging tools like

[**fiddler**](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

[**firebug**](http://getfirebug.com/)