# request info in ajax done callback

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using an Ajax request to get data from my server. The data I get come from several places (urls). I need a way to distinguish between data that comes from one url and the data coming from another url. 
The request is like this:

```
function initRequest(url)
    var request = $.ajax({
            url: url,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "GET"
        });

        request.done(function(msg) {
            //i need to know what was the url of this request
            //request.url is undefined 
        }
}
```

How do I do this?
I mention that I cannot use the data itself (msg) to know the source url.

Comment: Your `url` parameter's value should still be in scope inside the callback passed to `done`, so you could try just using that?

Comment: If multiple calls are made before the `done` is called, the `url` has different values

Comment: @GeenHenk Uhh, no, considering each call would be using a different `jqXhr` object initialised in individual calls to that function.

Comment: @GeenHenk no, as `url` is a function parameter each invocation will be scope bound to the passed value, not the "current" value.

Comment: is this `.done` function guaranteed to be in the lexical scope of `initRequest` ?

Comment: in request.done(function(msg){}) request.url is undefined

Comment: Use `this.url` (see answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't modify the returned JSON, use the url of the ajax object inside the callback:

```
.done(function(msg) { 
    var url = this.url; 
});
```

Comment: I cannot do this. The server is not mine, I just use it. I need on request.done to get the request url.

Comment: Oh now that makes more sense.. Better include that info in your question. I didn't get that out of your info

Comment: Thanks mate. This is the way to get that info. I already marked your answer as solution for my question, but please edit it to be clear - maybe someone else with the same issue will read this question. Just delete the server part from your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468312/access-the-url-of-an-jquery-ajax-request-in-the-callback-function). The `url` property is available in the callbacks.

Comment: ah, ok, good spot.  Note that this only works because the AJAX object is the default `this` context of the `.done` call, unless you've supplied an alternate one in the `$.ajax()` settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variable `url` inside the done callback because it is a closure variable

```
function initRequest(url)
    var request = $.ajax({
            url: url,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "GET"
        });

        request.done(function(msg, status, xhr) {
            //you can use url here because it is a closure function
            alert(url)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `.done` function is in the lexical scope of `initRequest`, just access the `url` parameter directly - it's still in scope.

Otherwise, so long as you haven't supplied an alternate `context` setting in the `$.ajax` call you can just access `this.url` in the `.done` callback - by default jQuery invokes all AJAX callbacks with the AJAX object (which happens to contain this property) as the context.